# Supervisor running queue:work but not executing queued laravel jobs

Tags: laravel-5, queue, supervisord

I've setup supervisor to run multiple instances of the following command.

```
php artisan queue:work --queue=default--tries=3
```

My default Queue is currently database as a proof of concept, before migrating to SQS.

My laravel-work.ini file looks like the below.

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php ~/www/artisan queue:work --queue=default--tries=3 --daemon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=5
stdout_logfile=~/www/storage/logs/workers.log
```

My `supervisorctl` output is as follows.

```
laravel-worker:laravel-worker_00   RUNNING   pid 34697, uptime 0:26:59
laravel-worker:laravel-worker_01   RUNNING   pid 34698, uptime 0:26:59
laravel-worker:laravel-worker_02   RUNNING   pid 34699, uptime 0:26:59
laravel-worker:laravel-worker_03   RUNNING   pid 34700, uptime 0:26:59
laravel-worker:laravel-worker_04   RUNNING   pid 34701, uptime 0:26:59
```

Not sure what I'm missing? But jobs in the database aren't getting processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--queue=default--tries=3
```

Was aactually a typo, so guessing artisan was trying to process a non existant queue with the name `default--tries=3`